# Android SeekBar with Thumb BELOW the bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to implement a Seek Bar following the design of the art team. They want a thumb that is not centered vertically, but rather below the progress bar (I would post a picture, but I don't have enough reputation yet to do it). I have been playing with the attributes like the `thumbOffset` that controls the horizontal offset, but I haven't been able to find anything to indicate a vertical offset or padding. As a result, I'm only able to get a seek bar where the thumb is centered vertically.

I have also tried to extend SeekBar but the method that is calculating the thumb position is private. Does anyone have a solution other than implement a completely new seek bar component from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea(I haven't tried it), make a seek bar below the one which you want the user to move, and make it invisible with `VIEW.INVISIBLE`. Then, in the invisible seek bar's `onSeekBarChangedListener`, set the first visible seek bar to the value that the second seek bar is on. And finally give the first seekbar the `setFocuseable(false)` , so that the user doesnt move the seek bar from the wrong place. If this doesn't make sense or work tell me and I will revise/delete this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion with some slights modifications and it worked. The upper seekbar had an invisible thumb (customized with the  `android:thumb` attribute) and the lower seekbar had an invisible progress and background (using the `android:progressDrawable` attribute). Then you need to keep both syncronized by code and that's all. Thanks for the idea.