# Make seekbar thumb appear below the bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my seekbar thumb to appear at the bottom of the bar. Is there a property way to achieve that?

```
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_seek_bar</item>

       <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/seek_bar_thumb</item>

      <item name="android:thumbOffset">0dip</item>

      <item name="android:minHeight">20dp</item>

      <item name="android:maxHeight">20dp</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Maybe a picture?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to put picture on stackoverflow. Basically, the thumb of a seekbar is positioned centered on the bar but i want it to be 3/4 below the progress

Comment: I think I know what you mean; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Seekbar with displaced thumb (at offset):**

[image: Seekbar with displaced thumb (at offset)]

Simply adjust the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` attributes by setting a style on the `SeekBar`:

```
    <item name="android:minHeight">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">60dp</item>
```

**Source:** Do the opposite of the fix shown here: http://qtcstation.com/2011/05/android-how-to-fix-seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues/

**Alternative solutions:**

1. Modify the thumb drawable using the `thumb` property in style, and add some invisible space at the top within the drawable so it looks like the thumb is displaced a little
2. Use two `SeekBar`s with one hidden and the other unfocusable... kind of like https://stackoverflow.com/a/13711256/832776 but you may need to modify their styles

Comment: should i place it in the drawable folder ?

Comment: Nope. In your layout XML that contains the `SeekBar`, set the `style` attribute. You can see how to do so here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Then mess around with the numbers above to set the offset as you wish.

Comment: i updated my question, i integrate the two line in the style.xml but the progress bar is changing not the thumb as in your picture

Comment: Try setting the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` to different values.

Comment: i tried with several values but i believe the maximum and minimum value is for the seekbar progress not the seekbar thumb

Comment: I can't mess around with the values at the moment but if you can't get it to work I added two more solutions to my answer above.

Comment: i did the second one it is working fine i used a seekbar but the progressbar and the thumb is not running parallel

Comment: I'm sure there is some adjustment you can make... if you want to learn even more look at the [`AbsSeekBar` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java#AbsSeekBar.setThumbOffset%28int%29) :) good luck!

Comment: Thank you Oleg Vaskevich. for sure i will take a look at it, have a nice day :)